# Considering total max records from the user and processing it based on the batch size in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to read the records from the source based on the count of total max records to be processed which should be given by the user.

Eg: Total Records in the source table is 1 million
Total Max records to process are 100K

I need to process those 100k records only from source.
I have gone through JDBC IO library classes to check if I have any option to implement it like there is an option to set the batch size,  but I have found none.

PS: I want to implement it IO level, Not by adding limit to query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using with setMaxRows by turning off the auto-commit for JDBC IO

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet how you used setmaxrecords?

Comment: that makes sense. You said you used setMaxRows which does not exist. In that case, you could have accepted my answer since setFetchSize worked for you as per my suggested answer.

Comment: oh Sorry, Actually I have tried the setFetchSize but it did not work for me,  setMaxRows worked for me! that was mistakenly posted. setMaxRows(100) fetches 100 records.

Comment: you are unwilling to use LIMIT 100 but happy to use setMaxRows(100). Thats strange. Glad that it works for you

Comment: My requirement is such!! Implementing limit in the query is different from reading from IO.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the withQuery to specify the query with the number of records to read e.g. `.withQuery("select id,name from Person limit 1000")`. You can also parameterize the number of records using `JdbcIO.StatementPreparator.` [The example in the doc may help](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html#method.summary).

**EDIT**
Another option is to use  [withFetchSize](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.Read.html#withFetchSize-int-)

Comment: I dont want to implement it with query as i mentioned in the question, as i will get memory issues while running multiple pipelines at once. I want to handle it in IO level @Tanveer Uddin

Comment: consider playing withFetchSize https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.Read.html#withFetchSize-int-

Comment: Yeap, I explored those and setMaxRows worked for me @Tanveer Uddin